# WCF:Unable to add service reference to silverlight project

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I faced a very odd problem, I'm using WCF Service since its earlier version but I didn't experience something like this. Today when I wanted to add Service to my Silverlight client application it shows an error which WCF Service is unable to generate WCF Service reference code. I don't know what's the problem everything I do is same as I did in previous projects.

Note that when I'm uncheck **Reuse types in all referenced assemblies** WCF can generate code for client.

Comment: The most likely reason is that you are returning some collection of a custom type from your service

Comment: Is there a type in that assembly in is not part of Silverlight? Some thing in .NET do not exist in Silverlight.

Comment: @prthrokz: No there is no custom collection.

Comment: @Justin Yes, telerik controls assemblies.

Comment: The telerik controls are probably compiled under .NET 4, so I am going to guess that is your problem. Can you test what happens if you exclude code in your server that uses the telerik stuff and generate the client code?

Comment: @Justin In server side there is no reference to Telerik controls, they are just used in Silverlight application.

Comment: I assume you have these types in a separate assembly/project. Can you change this project type to a portable class library?

Comment: @Saber I think this is a known issue with VS, I have faced it myself before. But in my case it was due to service returning a collection type. This would also magically start working if you delete the references and add them again or restart VS :/